# Synchronization problem while executing Simulink FMU in ROS 2-Gazebo (TF_OLD_DATA warning)

Tags: fmi

I'm working in a co-simulation project between Simulink and Gazebo. The aim is to move a robot model in Gazebo with the trajectory coordinates computed from Simulink. I'm using MATLAB R2022a, ROS 2 Dashing and Gazebo 9.9.0 in a computer running Ubuntu 18.04.

The problem is that when launching the FMU with the [fmi_adapter](https://github.com/boschresearch/fmi_adapter), I'm obtaining the following. It is tagged as [INFO], but actually messing up all my project.

```
[fmi_adapter_node-1] [INFO] [fmi_adapter_node]: Simulation time 1652274762.959713 is greater than timer's time 1652274762.901340. Is your step size to large?
```

Note the timer's time is higher than the simulation time. Even if I try to change the step size with the optional argument of the `fmi_adapter_node`, the same log appears with small differences in the times. I'm using the next commands:

```
ros2 launch fmi_adapter fmi_adapter_node.launch.py fmu_path:=FMI/Trajectory/RobotMARA_SimulinkFMU_v2.fmu # default step size: 0.2

ros2 launch fmi_adapter fmi_adapter_node.launch.py fmu_path:=FMI/Trajectory/RobotMARA_SimulinkFMU_v2.fmu _step_size:=0.001
```

As you would expect, the outputs of the FMU are the xyz coordinates of the robot trajectory in each time step. Since the fmi_adapter_node creates topics for both inputs and outputs, I'm reading the output xyz values by means of 3 subscribers with the [next](https://answers.ros.org/question/400122/return-a-value-from-a-callback-function-subscribing-to-topics-for-moveit_python_interface/) code. Then, those coordinates are being used to program the robot trajectories with the MoveIt-Python API.

When I run the previous Python code, I'm obtaining the following warning once and again and the robot manipulator actually doesn't move.

```
[ WARN] [1652274804.119514250]: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame motor6_link at time 870.266 according to authority unknown_publisher
Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
```

The previous warning is explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained), but I'm not able to fix it. I've tried clicking Reset in RViz, but nothing changes. I've also tried the following without success:

```
ros2 param set /fmi_adapter_node use_sim_time true # it just sets the timer's time to 0
```

It seems that the clock is taking negative values, so there is a synchronization problem.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message by the `FMIAdapterNode` is emitted if the timer's period is only slightly greater than the simulation step-size and if the timer is preempted by other processes or threads.

I created an issue at https://github.com/boschresearch/fmi_adapter/issues/9 which explains this in more detail and lists two possible fixes. It would be great if you could contribute to this discussion.

I assume that the TF_OLD_DATA error is not related to the fmi_adapter. Looking at the code snippet at [ROS Answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/400122/return-a-value-from-a-callback-function-subscribing-to-topics-for-moveit_python_interface/), I wondered whether x,y,z values are re-published at all given that the lines

```
pose.position.x = listener_x.value
pose.position.y = listener_y.value
pose.position.z = listener_z.value
```

are not inside a callback and executed even before rospy.spin(), but maybe that's just truncated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ralph. I did a test by decreasing the step size of my Simulink model before exporting the FMU (as suggested in the warning) and, when launching it in ROS, the warning has disappeared. The TF_OLD_DATA has nothing to do with the fmi_adapter as the warning persists even if the previous has been solved.

In addition, your work around for the subscribers was correct. With the previous code, I wasn't able to extract the coordinates values (they were 0 as initialized), while including them inside the callback yes.